# Does Urn of Shadows have a limit to charges, and what is it's radius on damage to enemies?

Tags: dota-2

I bought Urn of Shadows for the first time in my last match, and i was surprised at how useful it is.

I want to know is there a limit on the charges you can get on it, or can i just stack them up without worrying I'll hit the limit and waste a charge that way.

Comment: If you're curious why you at some point didn't gain a charge for a kill, it's most likely because one of your teammates also has an Urn.

Comment: @Decency Nah i know that, Iv'e read the item description. Only thing that wasn't there is whether it has limit charges or not. It doesn't say it does of course, but i know most items do have some kinds of limits so i just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no limit to the number of charges an [urn of shadows](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Urn_of_Shadows) can get.  But there should be no reason for you to save too many charges since they don't provide an additional benefit.  Also, remember that the heal/damage is a fixed value so the later the game goes, the less useful it is.

Also, the radius to cast the urn is 950 while the radius where it gains a charge is 1400.